# Difference between get_pages() and get_posts() functions in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am bit confused about above two. However, I am aware about the nature of both the functions.

```
1. get_pages() - fetches all pages from db.
2. get_posts() - fetches all posts from db.
```

But, my question is, when to use these functions? Do both of them return all the pages/posts which we can get through `WP_Query()` or do they both work in different ways?

Comment: @Paul Fioravanti, Thanks

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161558/24481 might helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `get_pages()`, you can set the type of post you are retrieving in the `post_type` parameter of the arguments. It returns an array of page objects that you can iterate over to display the contents. `get_posts()` is used when you want an array of post objects returned. This enables the use of specialized methods and properties when iterating over the returned array.

More about the difference can be found [here](https://www.digitalreachagency.com/2015/07/06/wp_query-vs-get_pages-vs-get_posts/).

Comment: ok thanks. but, However we can achieve both the things by using wp_query() class also then why these functions?

Comment: get_posts actually uses the wp_query class, but has more specialized results. The two methods you ask about are actually bits of syntactic sugar and it is not necessary to use them if you are comfortable with using wp_query directly.

Comment: Thanks. I got it this time.
Cheers!